# Can you interact with the app in test using absolute positioning in Detox?

Tags: detox

I am trying to test a react native app on android which uses a native library which does oauth-based authentication using a webview. Detox does not support webviews (yet) so I was wondering if I could tap on the keyboard using coordinates in order to get through the auth (bad I know, but gets me unstuck for now).

Answer (score 0):

Since the oauth screen is outside your app, I'd recommend you do the following:

1. Create E2E tests for your login up to the oauth screen
2. Get a CLI for your oauth provider or figure out how to authenticate via node.js to get the auth token
3. Create a deep link path in your app that accepts the token as a param and stores it the way you'd store it normally and trigger a continuation of the login flow (you may need to reverse engineer your native lib slightly)

This is generally the approach you want to take if you are using an external authentication party. If the party providing the auth package doesn't support 2 and 3, you should raise the issue with them.